# pip3 install jupyterlab fail on WSL2.0 under windows 10 arm64

Tags: python, gcc, arm64, wsl-2, argon2-cffi

Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL 2.0 under windows 10 ARM64 (Surface Pro X with WSL2.0).

```
pip3 install jupyterlab // failure
Building wheels for collected packages: argon2-cffi
  Building wheel for argon2-cffi (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp5k32hshp
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-jo5pljfy/argon2-cffi_f65af512bd344c9b956794545e86c839
  Complete output (39 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/argon2
  copying src/argon2/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/argon2
  copying src/argon2/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_password_hasher.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_ffi_build.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/argon2
  copying src/argon2/low_level.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_legacy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/argon2
  copying src/argon2/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/argon2
  running build_clib
  building 'argon2' library
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src/blake2
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/argon2.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src/argon2.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/blake2/blake2b.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src/blake2/blake2b.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/core.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src/core.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/encoding.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src/encoding.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/ref.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src/ref.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/thread.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src/thread.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar rcs build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/libargon2.a build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src/argon2.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src/blake2/blake2b.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src/core.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/extras/libargon2/src/encoding.o build/temp.linux-aar  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iextras/libargon2/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/_ffi.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/_ffi.o
  build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/_ffi.c:50:14: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
     50 | #    include <pyconfig.h>
        |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi
Failed to build argon2-cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for argon2-cffi which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

How can I build argon2-cffi successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it following these steps:

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential python3.8-dev // ubuntu 20.04
pip3 install pep517 // or python3.8 -m pip install pep517
pip3 install jupyterlab // successfully
```